# Asp.Net caching pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

There are a great number of articles available regarding thread safe caching, here's an example:

```
private static object _lock =  new object();

public void CacheData()
{
   SPListItemCollection oListItems;
       oListItems = (SPListItemCollection)Cache["ListItemCacheName"];
      if(oListItems == null)
      {
         lock (_lock) 
         {
              // Ensure that the data was not loaded by a concurrent thread 
              // while waiting for lock.
              oListItems = (SPListItemCollection)Cache[“ListItemCacheName”];
              if (oListItems == null)
              {
                   oListItems = DoQueryToReturnItems();
                   Cache.Add("ListItemCacheName", oListItems, ..);
              }
         }
     }
}
```

However, this example depends on the request for the cache also rebuilding the cache.

I'm looking for a solution where the request and rebuild are separate. Here's the scenario.

I have a web service that I want to monitor for certain types of error. If an error occurs, I create an monitor object and cache - it is updatable and is locked accordingly during update. Alls well so far.

Elsewhere, I check for the existence of the cached object, and the data it contains. This would work straight out of the box except for one particular scenario.

If the cache object is being updated - say a status change, I would like to wait and get the latest info rather than the current info, which if returned, would be out of date. So for my fetch code, I need to check if the object is currently being created/updating, and if so wait, then retry.

As I pointed out, there are many examples of cache locking patterns but I can't seem to find one that for this scenario. Any ideas as to how to go about this would be appreciated?

Comment: Why don't you simply implement the locking you need in your cached object's "UpdateStatus" and "GetLatestInfo" methods?

Comment: I'm not really confident in this - yes I could implement locking in the update status, but I'm not too sure about the get info - do I just lock?

Comment: yes - the object you put in the Cache should be thread-safe, so you should typically use the same lock for updates and get info.  IMHO the locking you use to ensure internally in your class to ensure this thread-safety should be completely independent of any locking you use to ensure you're accessing the same instance in the Cache.  If you aren't confident, I suggest you post an implementation and ask another question about its thread-safety.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code using two locks. Write lock in the setter is quite simple and protects cache from being written by more than one threads. The getter use a simple [double-check lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

Now, the trick is in `Refresh()` method, which uses the same lock as the getter. The method uses the lock and in the first step removes list from the cache. It will trigger any getter to fail the first null check and wait for the lock. The method in the meantime gets items, sets cache again and releases the lock. 
When it comes back to the getter, it reads the cache again and now it contains the list.

```
public class CacheData
{
    private static object _readLock = new object();
    private static object _writeLock = new object();

    public SPListItemCollection ListItem
    {
        get
        {

            var oListItems = (SPListItemCollection) Cache["ListItemCacheName"];
            if (oListItems == null)
            {
                lock (_readLock)
                {
                    oListItems = (SPListItemCollection)Cache["ListItemCacheName"];
                    if (oListItems == null)
                    {
                        oListItems = DoQueryToReturnItems();
                        Cache.Add("ListItemCacheName", oListItems, ..);
                    }
                }
            }
            return oListItems;
        }

        set
        {
            lock (_writeLock)
            {
                Cache.Add("ListItemCacheName", value, ..);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        lock (_readLock)
        {
            Cache.Remove("ListItemCacheName");
            var oListItems = DoQueryToReturnItems();
            ListItem = oListItems;                
        }
    }
}
```

You can make the method and property static, if you do not need `CacheData` instance.